# Apollo Client - use Query doesn't re-render when data arives

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo-client

I'm working on a Nextjs app.

The app fetches data using graphql from the server.

The server is a `postgraphile` server.

I generate the `Apollo-clinet` `hooks` with `graphql-codegen`

I encounter the following issue:

useQuery requests data successfully, the data is shown in the network tab in the browser, but the hook doesn't re-render with the data.

The hook state stays the same: `{data: undefined, error: undefined, loading: true}.`

If I save a file and a hot reload occurs, the hook fires with the updated state:

```
{data: some_data, error: undefined, loading: false}
```

I tried changing the apollo-client to several different versions based on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9602
Nothing worked.

I tried debugging the node_module itself but didn't find the issue.

I tried setting the `fetchPolicy` to `cache-first,` `network-first,` and `cache-and-network,` but nothing worked.

The only thing that worked was calling the hook in a provider component. I don't know why.

Does anyone is familiar with that issue? And maybe have a cleaner solution?

I assume it has something to do with the cache.

This is the useQuery hook:

```
  const { data: primaryRunsData, loading } = usePrimaryRunsQuery();
```

**Graphql Query**

```
   query PrimaryRuns(
  $first: Int = 10
  $filter: ShellRunFilter = {
    run: { id: { equalTo: "4acf2d7c-9a70-42f6-9fb7-bd7cb9e3c182" } }
  }
) {
  shellRuns(
    first: $first
    filter: $filter
    orderBy: MULTILATERAL_TRADE_POPULATIONS_PREPARATION_BY_RUN_ID__EXECUTION_TIME_ASC
  ) {
    nodes {
      run {
        ...ShellRunData
      }
      shell {
        name
        shellRunsList(filter: { executionCandidate: { equalTo: false } }) {
          run {
            ...ShellRunData
          }
        }
      }
    }
    totalCount
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a useEffect in a Provider component that calls two async functions that set state in them. After commenting out the second call the useQuery state updated correctly.

Also, there is a call to `clearCache` in the setter function. which, deletes any data that was previously returned in the network.

```
  useEffect(() => {
const lastActingAs = Number(localStorage.getItem(ACTING_AS_KEY));
if (!actingAs && availableOrgs) {
// async  
setActingAs(isActingAsValid ? lastActingAs : availableOrgs[0].id, true);
}
if (!groupedActingAs && orgTreeData) {
  //async
  setActingAs(
    isGroupedActingAsValid ? lastActingAs : user.parentOrg,
    true,
    setGroupedActingAs,
  );
}
}, [availableOrgs, orgTreeData]);


  const setActingAs = async (
orgId: number,
keepQuery?: boolean,
setActinAsOrg: ActingAsSetter = _setActingAs,
) => {
try {
  await axios(setActingAsApi(orgId));
  await client.clearStore();
  clearCache();
  setActinAsOrg(orgId);
  localStorage.setItem(ACTING_AS_KEY, String(orgId));
  if (!keepQuery) {
    resetQueryParams();
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log('helo', error);
}
};
```

Not sure why it affects the useQuery hook.
Can someone explain?